# Using MVC Client side Data Annotation validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am using MVC Data Annotation validation with a bootstrap 4 accordion. I want the MVC Data Annotation validation to kick in on the accordion using the AddRecommendation button but I can't get it to flag the controls. I tried `.validate().element("#collapse1");` but that is not working and its not setting the controls to the color red

HTML

```
   <div id="accordion">
      <div  iv class="card">
         <div class="card-header">
             <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Recommended 1</a>
         </div>
         <div id="collapse1" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
         <div class="card-body">
         <div class="form-group row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.recommendationData[0].SpecificChangeRecommended)<b style="color:red">*</b>
             @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.recommendationData[0].SpecificChangeRecommended, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SpecificChangeRecommended" })                                           
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.recommendationData[0].SpecificChangeRecommended, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
         </div>
       </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
         <div class="row d-flex justify-content-right submission">
         <div class="col-md-12">
             <button type="button" class="btn" id="btnAddRecommendation">
                 Save Recommendation
            </button>
         </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
 $("#btnAddRecommendation").click(function (event) {
     console.log('%c btnAddRecommendation! ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
     var container = $("#frmFullSubmissionRequest").validate().element("#collapse1");
     container.valid();
 });
```

Comment: $("#btnAddRecommendation").click(function (event) {
    console.log('%c btnAddRecommendation! ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
    var form = $("#frmFullSubmissionRequest");
    form.validate();
    form.valid();
});

Comment: But that will do the other elements outside of the panel? How can I just do the elements in the panel?

Comment: $("#btnAddRecommendation").click(function (event) {
    console.log('%c btnAddRecommendation! ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
    var specificChangeRecommended = $("#SpecificChangeRecommended");
    specificChangeRecommended.valid();
});

Comment: Yes but that is just one element in the card-body what if I have more elements ?